# ¿Como visualizar en PyQGIS, un raster de un WMS en formato JPG?, con formato PNG si se muestra

Tags: python, pyqgis

tengo el raster del catastro http://ovc.catastro.meh.es/Cartografia/WMS/ServidorWMS.aspx?version%3D1.3.0, para visualizarlo en mi visor de PyQGIS, si la imagen al abrirlo es JPG, no veo nada y si es PNG, lo veo sin problemas. Me pasa lo mismo con otros wms que solo se muestran en JPG.

No se si me falta cargar importar algún módulo o librería adicional

Añado el código para comentar que sucede

Este es el código

```
import sys
import os
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

os.environ['QGIS_PREFIX_PATH'] = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS 3.12\apps\qgis'

class MyWnd(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Datos Catastrales")

# En esta variable conecto al servidor WMS y especifico que la imagen es PNG

        urlStr = "url=http://ovc.catastro.meh.es/Cartografia/WMS/ServidorWMS.aspx?version%3D1.3.0&contextualWMSLegend=0&crs=EPSG:32628&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&format=image/png&&layers=Catastro&styles"

        self.layerCat=QgsRasterLayer(urlStr,"CatastroWMS","wms")
        self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        self.canvas.setLayers([self.layerCat])
        self.canvas.setExtent(self.layerCat.extent())
        self.canvas.setCanvasColor(QtCore.Qt.white)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)


def main(argv):

    app = QgsApplication([], True)
    app.initQgis()

    w = MyWnd()
    w.show()        

    retval = app.exec_()
    app.exitQgis()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

En la variable  "urlStr" especifico la conexión al wms especificando un tipo de imagen PNG ("&format=image/png"), la imagen se visualiza correctamente.

Si quiero visualizar la misma imagen especificando un formato JPG ("&format=image/jpg"), no se visualiza absolutamente nada.

Me pasa con otros WMS que solo se pueden visualizar con formato JPG

Espero haber aclarado un poco más la situación

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Deberías comprobar que el formato JPEG es soportado por el servicio WMS, realizando una operación GetCapabilities.

Comment: La URL publicada no conduce a nada.

Comment: Puedes publicar el codigo, trazas de error, etc? Tal y como está formulada la pregunta es imposible ayudarte y es posible que la marquen para cerrar.